# Custom Fancybox gallery

Tags: fancybox

I am using fancybox to load all images in my application. As of now, i am creating my own methods for Next & Previous links and not using fancybox ones. The output is like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIcih.jpg (Desired output)

But the only problem is, upon clicking, i am changing the images, which is taking some time.

Now, i want to use fancybox gallery, because i have all URLs and titles with me in an json array. So i did something like this and now i am getting this as output. (http://i.imgur.com/JNfmz.png)

All i want is, The (desired output) with images much easier to load.

```
$.fancybox([{href : 'image.jpg', title : 'Lorem lipsum'},{href : 'image.jpg', title : 'Lorem lipsum'}]);
```

Can i make it look like my desired output, means can i add custom content?

Comment: does your document have a valid `DOCTYPE`? ... [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your document and look for inconsistencies.

Comment: @JFK my doctype : **<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">**

Comment: got a link? ... it would be easier to track the issue down

Comment: You mean like jsfiddle? I am preparing now and will post it soon